# MySQL fails persistently after power removal (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, raspberry-pi2

I have a small Python script that monitors a couple of GPIO pins and logs their states to an MySQL database. Every couple of minutes, it bundles all of these local observations up and POSTs them to a server for storage and analysis.

If the Pi loses power at the wrong time (I suspect when it's mid transaction) the MySQL database refuses to start when it powers back up (and for all subsequent reboots). It looks like a number of the system tables get corrupted - I can fix this with mysqlcheck and a lot of mucking about but that's frustrating, so I just keep a couple of working SD cards and swap them in + re-image the corrupted one (usually this only costs me a few minutes of data on the old card).

Is this a common issue and is there a way to prevent it? I'm contemplating switching to CSVs or something a little more fault-tolerant but surely MySQL has some robust mode that could survive these power-down events, or a flag that can attempt auto-recovery without supervision when things go wrong?

Comment: Why not use SQLite and create the tables/file each time you start up. You seem to be using it only for cache anyway.

Comment: At least take a peak into transactions when you expect this behavior more often.

Comment: Add a UPS to your RPI, and configure it to power-down after loss of power.